# Displaying content on posts page based on category

Tags: php, posts, filters

Typically if I wanted to have content based on what page someone was on I could do something like

```
if (is_page('contact')) {
    #code block here
```

but what about if what want is based on the category of posts? like if the user wanted to filter event type or by state, for this example, lets say by state. This is the current url

```
/category/upcoming-events
```

so not really a "page". I wanted to hide some menus and display others if they visit a specific category.

I found in the WordPress documentation that there is this a function for category, but not really sure how to implement anything in their documentation. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Perhaps something like

```
is_category( 'upcoming-events' ) {
    echo '<ul class="state">' . #the rest of the code here . '</ul>';

}
```

and really since I should not add the code there and use a template perhaps

```
is_category( 'upcoming-events' ) {
    echo <?php get_template_part('part-template-event-filter'); ?>;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For category check, the CODE would be:

```
if( is_category( 'upcoming-events' ) ) {
    get_template_part('part-template-event-filter');
}
```